# Codeigniter temporary password validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, passwords, migration, password-protection

I'm trying to come up with a simple solution for a scenario and hoping to get some opinions.  We're in the process of porting a web app to Codeigniter with Ion Auth authentication.  Since password encryption in Codeigniter differs from our current hashing method, all users are going to need new passwords.  What I was thinking is having default passwords for every user, for example, every user's password will exists in the db as the encrypted version of their email address they used to sign up.  Once the user logs into the new Codeigniter app for the first time, I'd like to set up some sort of temporary validation that prompts them to change their password before continuing.

Any suggestions on the simplest approach to accomplishing this?  I'm also open to better ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if a understand the question and I don't know Ion Auth, but that is the way I did something similar.

All my controllers are extending a "parent controller" which verifies the status of the user's password in his constructor. (The user model is autoloaded.)

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $userId = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $user = $this->user_model->find($userId);

        if ($user->password_expired_date <= date('Y-m-d')) {
            redirect('profile/change_password');
        }
    }
}

class AnyController extends MY_Controller
{
    /* 
        stuff
     */
}
```

In my case there is a password expiration date, but you can also have a custom field like "password_changed" or "password_times_changed" with default 0.